# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: when executing ServerBuilder.forPort(50051)

Tags: java, gradle, grpc, guava, grpc-java

I tried to run a simple gRPC-java example, however I came across the following error that I can't solve

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(50051)
            .addService(serviceTeste)
            .build();

    server.start();
    server.awaitTermination();
```

I had the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, char, java.lang.Object)'
at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.validateName(Metadata.java:742)
at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:750)
at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.<init>(Metadata.java:668)
at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:959)
at io.grpc.Metadata$AsciiKey.<init>(Metadata.java:954)
at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:705)
at io.grpc.Metadata$Key.of(Metadata.java:701)
at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.<clinit>(GrpcUtil.java:81)
at io.grpc.netty.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:79)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder.<clinit>(NettyServerBuilder.java:83)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerProvider.builderForPort(NettyServerProvider.java:40)
at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerProvider.builderForPort(NettyServerProvider.java:25)
at io.grpc.ServerBuilder.forPort(ServerBuilder.java:44)
at MindViewerTest.Main.main(Main.java:179)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

I've already tried to update Guava, but to no avail, as can be seen in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'io.vacco.java-express:java-express:0.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.14'

compile "io.grpc:grpc-netty:${grpcVersion}"
compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java-util', version: '3.12.2'

compileOnly group: "javax.annotation", name: "javax.annotation-api", version: "1.3.2"
compileOnly group: "org.jetbrains", name: "annotations", version: "13.0"
```

}

Comment: what exactly do you think that error message means to tell you?

Comment: Have you tried updating gRPC itself already, by any chance?

Comment: @jbduncan yes, gRPC is at version 1.39.0, which from what I've seen is the latest version